# Initial Startup of Wso2 Identity 5.10 is giving error: Admin user can not be assigned to Admin role

Tags: wso2, wso2-identity-server

I've reviewed a lot of answers to similar questions but cannot find this one.  On startup I get:

```
[2022-01-15 12:56:48,823] []  INFO {org.ops4j.pax.logging.spi.support.EventAdminConfigurationNotifier} - Sending Event Admin nofification (configuration successful) to org/ops4j/pax/logging/Configuration
[2022-01-15 12:56:49,009] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Starting WSO2 Carbon...
[2022-01-15 12:56:49,010] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Operating System : Linux 3.10.0-1160.49.1.el7.x86_64, amd64
[2022-01-15 12:56:49,011] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java Home        : /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.8.0-openjdk-1.8.0.312.b07-1.el7_9.x86_64/jre
[2022-01-15 12:56:49,011] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java Version     : 1.8.0_312
[2022-01-15 12:56:49,011] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java VM          : OpenJDK 64-Bit Server VM 25.312-b07,Red Hat, Inc.
[2022-01-15 12:56:49,011] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Carbon Home      : /u01/ellucian/wso2is-5.10.0
[2022-01-15 12:56:49,011] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - Java Temp Dir    : /u01/ellucian/wso2is-5.10.0/tmp
[2022-01-15 12:56:49,011] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.core.internal.CarbonCoreActivator} - User             : root, en-US, America/New_York
[2022-01-15 12:56:49,108] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.internal.DefaultCryptoProviderComponent} - 'CryptoService.Secret' property has not been set. 'org.wso2.carbon.crypto.provider.SymmetricKeyInternalCryptoProvider' won't be registered as an internal crypto provider. Please set the secret if the provider needs to be registered.
[2022-01-15 12:56:49,234] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.event.output.adapter.kafka.internal.ds.KafkaEventAdapterServiceDS} - Successfully deployed the Kafka output event adaptor service
[2022-01-15 12:56:49,721] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.uma.grant.internal.UMA2GrantServiceComponent} - Policy evaluator registered successfully: DefaultPolicyEvaluator
[2022-01-15 12:56:49,722] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.oauth.uma.grant.internal.UMA2GrantServiceComponent} - UMA Grant component activated successfully.
[2022-01-15 12:56:50,075] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.ldap.server.DirectoryActivator} - Embedded LDAP is disabled.
[2022-01-15 12:56:50,119] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mex.internal.Office365SupportMexComponent} - Office365Support MexServiceComponent bundle activated successfully..
[2022-01-15 12:56:50,132] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.mex2.internal.DynamicCRMCustomMexComponent} - DynamicCRMSupport MexServiceComponent bundle activated successfully.
[2022-01-15 12:56:51,436] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService} - Database already exists. Not creating a new database.
[2022-01-15 12:56:51,859] []  INFO {org.apache.jasper.servlet.TldScanner} - At least one JAR was scanned for TLDs yet contained no TLDs. Enable debug logging for this logger for a complete list of JARs that were scanned but no TLDs were found in them. Skipping unneeded JARs during scanning can improve startup time and JSP compilation time.
[2022-01-15 12:56:52,175] []  INFO {org.wso2.carbon.identity.authenticator.x509Certificate.internal.X509CertificateServiceComponent} - X509 Certificate Servlet activated successfully..
[2022-01-15 12:56:52,427] [] ERROR {org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm} - nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: nullType class java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:397)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.initializeObjects(DefaultRealm.java:224)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.init(DefaultRealm.java:129)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.initializeRealm(DefaultRealmService.java:276)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:102)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealmService.<init>(DefaultRealmService.java:115)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.Activator.startDeploy(Activator.java:72)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.internal.BundleCheckActivator.start(BundleCheckActivator.java:61)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:842)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl$3.run(BundleContextImpl.java:1)
        at java.security.AccessController.doPrivileged(Native Method)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.startActivator(BundleContextImpl.java:834)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.BundleContextImpl.start(BundleContextImpl.java:791)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle.startWorker0(EquinoxBundle.java:1013)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxBundle$EquinoxModule.startWorker(EquinoxBundle.java:365)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.doStart(Module.java:598)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.Module.start(Module.java:462)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel$1.run(ModuleContainer.java:1820)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.internal.framework.EquinoxContainerAdaptor$2$1.execute(EquinoxContainerAdaptor.java:150)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1813)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.incStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1770)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.doContainerStartLevel(ModuleContainer.java:1735)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1661)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.container.ModuleContainer$ContainerStartLevel.dispatchEvent(ModuleContainer.java:1)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager.dispatchEvent(EventManager.java:234)
        at org.eclipse.osgi.framework.eventmgr.EventManager$EventThread.run(EventManager.java:345)
Caused by: java.lang.reflect.InvocationTargetException
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method)
        at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62)
        at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45)
        at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.DefaultRealm.createObjectWithOptions(DefaultRealm.java:351)
        ... 25 more
Caused by: org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user can not be assigned to Admin role Add-Admin has been set to false. Please do the assign it in user store level
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.common.AbstractUserStoreManager.addInitialAdminData(AbstractUserStoreManager.java:8513)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadOnlyLDAPUserStoreManager.java:246)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.<init>(ReadWriteLDAPUserStoreManager.java:120)
        at org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.<init>(ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager.java:115)
        ... 30 more
```

using ldapsearch I've checked on some of those properties, but specifically here are segments of the admin user object related to being a member of the admin role as queried by the service account.  Both do exist:

```
./ldapsearch -x -W -H ldap://VPWPWDC1.DC1.PENNWEST.EDU/ -D "ethossrvc@pennwest.edu" -b "CN=Staffen\, William,OU=STAFF,OU=Accounts,DC=DC1,DC=Pennwest,DC=EDU"

dn: CN=Staffen\, William,OU=Staff,OU=Accounts,DC=DC1,DC=PENNWEST,DC=EDU
objectClass: top
objectClass: person
objectClass: organizationalPerson
objectClass: user
cn: Staffen, William
sn: Staffen
givenName: William
distinguishedName: CN=Staffen\, William,OU=Staff,OU=Accounts,DC=DC1,DC=PENNWEST,DC=EDU
instanceType: 4
memberOf: CN=AG-ITS-ETHOS-ADMINS,OU=ITS,OU=AccountGroups,OU=Groups,DC=DC1,DC=PENNWEST,DC=EDU
```

Here is the user-mgt.xml:

```
<UserManager xmlns:svns="http://org.wso2.securevault/configuration">
    17      <Realm>
    18          <Configuration>
    19              <AddAdmin>false</AddAdmin>
    20              <AdminRole>AG-ITS-ETHOS-ADMINS</AdminRole>
    21              <AdminUser>
    22                  <UserName>staffen</UserName>
    23                  <Password>irrelevant</Password>
    24              </AdminUser>
    25              <EveryOneRoleName>everyone</EveryOneRoleName>
    26
    27              <OverrideUsernameClaimFromInternalUsername>true</OverrideUsernameClaimFromInternalUsername>
    28              <!-- By default users in this role sees the registry root -->
    29              <Property name="isCascadeDeleteEnabled">true</Property>
    30              <Property name="initializeNewClaimManager">true</Property>
    31              <Property name="dataSource">jdbc/WSO2IdentityDB</Property>
    32          </Configuration>
    33          
    34
    35          <AuthorizationManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.authorization.JDBCAuthorizationManager">
    36              <Property name="GetAllRolesOfUserEnabled">false</Property>
    37              <Property name="AdminRoleManagementPermissions">/permission</Property>
    38              <Property name="AuthorizationCacheEnabled">true</Property>
    39          </AuthorizationManager>
    40      
    41
    42
    43
    44
    45  <UserStoreManager class="org.wso2.carbon.user.core.ldap.ActiveDirectoryUserStoreManager">
    46                  <Property name="TenantManager">org.wso2.carbon.user.core.tenant.CommonHybridLDAPTenantManager</Property>
    47                  <Property name="defaultRealmName">PENNWEST.EDU</Property>
    48                  <Property name="Disabled">false</Property>                                   
    49                  <Property name="kdcEnabled">false</Property>
    50                  <Property name="ConnectionURL">ldaps://VPWPWDC1.DC1.PENNWEST.EDU:636</Property> 
    51                  <Property name="ConnectionName">CN=SRVC_ethossrvc,OU=Accounts,OU=ServiceAG,DC=DC1,DC=PENNWEST,DC=EDU</Property>
    52                  <Property name="ConnectionPassword">#########</Property>
    53                  <Property name="passwordHashMethod">PLAIN_TEXT</Property>
    54                  <Property name="UserSearchBase">OU=Accounts,DC=DC1,DC=PENNWEST,DC=EDU</Property>
    55                  <Property name="UserEntryObjectClass">user</Property>
    56                  <Property name="UserNameAttribute">sAMAccountName</Property>
    57                  <Property name="isADLDSRole">false</Property>
    58                  <Property name="userAccountControl">512</Property>
    59                  <Property name="UserNameListFilter">(objectClass=user)</Property>
    60                  <Property name="UserNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=person)(|(sAMAccountName=?)(mail=?)))</Property>
    61                  <Property name="UsernameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
    62                  <Property name="UsernameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
    63                  <Property name="PasswordJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{5,30}$</Property>
    64                  <Property name="RolenameJavaScriptRegEx">^[\S]{3,30}$</Property>
    65                  <Property name="RolenameJavaRegEx">[a-zA-Z0-9._-|//]{3,30}$</Property>
    66                  <Property name="ReadGroups">true</Property>
    67                  <Property name="WriteGroups">true</Property>
    68                  <Property name="EmptyRolesAllowed">true</Property>
    69                  <Property name="GroupSearchBase">OU=AccountGroups,OU=Groups,DC=DC1,DC=PENNWEST,DC=EDU</Property>
    70                  <Property name="GroupEntryObjectClass">group</Property>
    71                  <Property name="GroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
    72                  <Property name="SharedGroupNameAttribute">cn</Property>
    73                  <Property name="SharedGroupSearchBase">OU=AccountGroups,OU=Groups,DC=DC1,DC=PENNWEST,DC=EDU</Property>
    74                  <Property name="SharedGroupEntryObjectClass">groups</Property>
    75                  <Property name="SharedTenantNameListFilter">(object=organizationalUnit)</Property>
    76                  <Property name="SharedTenantNameAttribute">ou</Property>
    77                  <Property name="SharedTenantObjectClass">organizationalUnit</Property>
    78                  <Property name="MembershipAttribute">member</Property>
    79                  <Property name="GroupNameListFilter">(objectcategory=group)</Property>
    80                  <Property name="GroupNameSearchFilter">(&amp;(objectClass=group)(cn=?))</Property>
    81                  <Property name="UserRolesCacheEnabled">true</Property>
    82                  <Property name="Referral">ignore</Property>
    83                  <Property name="BackLinksEnabled">true</Property>
    84                  <Property name="MaxRoleNameListLength">100</Property>
    85                  <Property name="MaxUserNameListLength">100</Property>
    86                  <Property name="SCIMEnabled">false</Property>
    87                  <Property name="MultiAttributeSeparator">,</Property>
    88                  <Property name="ReadTimeout"/>
    89                  <Property name="RetryAttempts"/>
    90
    91                                  <Property name="java.naming.ldap.attributes.binary">objectGUID</Property>
    92                                  <Property name="ImmutableAttributes">profileConfiguration</Property>
    93                          </UserStoreManager>
    94  </Realm>
    95  </UserManager>
```

Any help is appreciated.

EDIT: Also of note: I connected to the sql server as the wso2 admin user for each of the three databases (local, reg, and id) and was able to connect open each and view the tables.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are getting an error saying,

`org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Admin user can not be assigned to Admin role Add-Admin has been set to false. Please do the assign it in user store level`

in WSO2IS-5.10 you can set `<AddAdmin>true</AddAdmin>` in */repository/conf/user-mgt.xml* file , in your *user-mgt.xml* file it is in *false* state

Comment: AddAdmin is false because we don't want it creating users or roles in the AD.

Comment: Since the service account has no write access to AD, I flipped this to true just to see what new error it gave me when it found it couldn't actually add users or roles.  It did give an error: "Error occurred while setting SCIM attributes for the Admin org.wso2.carbon.user.core.UserStoreException: Error in adding SCIM metadata to the admin in tenant domain: carbon.super" but the service started, too.  So ty.  Why a r/w field would need to be set to true whether it can write or not is beyond me; I don't even know what the purpose of the field would be. Thank you.

Comment: Hi, this issue can be fixed by mapping the claims, https://github.com/wso2/product-is/issues/2409